# Auto mount SD card (say 128GB) after suspend and then resume

Tags: mount, suspend, sd-card

Here is what I do on my Kubuntu 14.04

1. I gave the permission to my user (say xyz) to `/bin/mount` with no password using following

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```

   add below line

   ```
   xyz ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
   ```
2. Then added a new script say `run.sh` to `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   case "$1" in

     ;;
     resume) 
       sleep 2
       sudo /bin/mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/xyz/SD8

     ;;
     *)
     ;;
   esac
   ```

Here `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is my SD memory card

3. Check by executing command

   ```
   sudo pm-suspend
   ```

It mounts, but it in read only mode. How can I mount it read-write?

Comment: **Edit tip**: If you use numbers and use code segments together, you need to add an additional 4 spaces manually to indent into "code space"  ;-)

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: @ElderGeek I made it into a question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Placed this script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` and everything works fine! No need to use `visudo`

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in    
  ;;
  resume) 
    sleep 1
    su xyz -c "udisksctl mount -b /dev/mmcblk0p1"

  ;;
  *)

  ;;
esac
```